Android Coil loads removes old image to early when loading new image
So I have image that is shown and over that image I load another image like this:
 AsyncImage(
            modifier = modifier,
            model = modelBuilder(
                ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
                    .data(image.url)
                    .loadWitchCache(image.url)
                    .let {
                        if (placeholder != null) {
                            it.fallback(placeholder).error(placeholder)
                        } else {
                            it
                        }
                    },
                image.url,
            ).build(),
            contentDescription = contentDescription,
            alignment = alignment,
            contentScale = contentScale,
        )




fun ImageRequest.Builder.loadWitchCache(url: String): ImageRequest.Builder {
return this.diskCachePolicy(CachePolicy.ENABLED)
    .diskCacheKey(url)
    .memoryCachePolicy(CachePolicy.ENABLED)
    .memoryCacheKey(url)

}
The problem is that in app I have list of images that user can pick. When he picks image, it is drawn. Problem is that when I choose new image, there is transition where I don't see old or new image. I see Image that is placeholder under that. What is interesting is that when user picks second or third time the same image, than there is no this transition delay and all we can see is old image and imediatly new one when loaded.
This takes us to conclusion that when image is cached, it takes it from cache and there is not this delay. But why can't we tell Coil to do it anyways and remove old image only when new is loaded...
I tried lot of things, but nothing helped. It has to be some way.
Anyone knows to solve it? Thanks in advance...

Please provide a [mre] of the transition you are talking about and a way for us to execute it so we can reproduce the issue.

"But why can't we tell Coil to do it anyways and remove old image only when new is loaded" -- Jetpack Compose is declarative, so there is no "old image" or "new image", only "the current image". Perhaps you should not be using your placeholder parameter in this case, but instead use a reference to the "old image", such as is described here and here.

Or, preload the new image, and only update the composable once the preload request has completed.

@CommonsWare yes that is solution. My collegues and me fixed it and I just saw your idea. Down is the answer. Thanks a lot for the answer!

Here is solution guys. CommonsWare got the right idea:
 var oldImage: Drawable? by remember {
    mutableStateOf(null)
}
when (image) {
    is ImageResource.ByUrl -> {
        AsyncImage(
            modifier = modifier,
            model = modelBuilder(
                ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
                    .data(image.url)
                    .placeholder(oldImage)
                    .loadWitchCache(image.url)
                    .listener(onSuccess = { _, successResult ->
                        oldImage = successResult.drawable
                    })
                    .let {
                        if (placeholder != null) {
                            it.fallback(placeholder).error(placeholder)
                        } else {
                            it
                        }
                    },
                image.url,
            ).build(),
            contentDescription = contentDescription,
            alignment = alignment,
            contentScale = contentScale,
        )
    }

